# Can't resolve BitBucket git conflict

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm trying to merge development into master, but I'm getting merge conflicts.

```
Merge pull request
 Bitbucket cannot automatically merge this request due to conflicts.

Review the conflicts on the Overview tab. You can then either decline the request or merge it manually on your local system using the following commands:

git checkout master
git merge --no-ff -m 'Merged in development (pull request #85)' remotes/origin/development
```

Bitbucket tells me I should checkout master locally, and resolve the conflicts. But if I do that there are no merge conflicts to fix. Furthermore it tells me Master is up to date.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

(I assume the name of the development branch is `dev`, replace it with the actual name)

1. `git merge --abort`
2. `git fetch origin`
3. `git checkout master`
4. `git merge origin/master` # merges latest changes from origin to the local master
5. Fix conflicts if any then `git add .` ;  `git commit` # fix conflicts if any and commit the merge
6. `git checkout dev` # switch to the dev (replace to actual the branch name) branch
7. `git merge origin/dev` # merge the latest changes from the remote dev branch to the local dev branch, fix conflicts if any
8. `git merge master` # merge master into dev, fix conflicts if any
9. `git push origin HEAD:dev`

The merge conflicts from the PR should be gone

Comment: After 1 I get "fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing)."

Comment: Good, ignore the first step then

Comment: After 4 it still claims "Already up to date."

I tried the other way (since everything I want is on development on bitbucket) and it still claims everything is up to date.

I have a suspicion that this is a permissions issue (I can merge into dev but not push directly) but the guy in charge of it is gone.

Comment: I just went the nuclear option of redownloading the repository, and still nothing

Comment: "still nothing" how? Could you elaborate on it please? After you redownload the repo the error persists?

Comment: It's still showing me master without the conflicts on my machine.

Comment: Do you want the conflicts to appear? Are you trying to merge the dev branch to master locally or on the bitbucket UI?

Comment: I want them to appear so I can fix them.

This is what I do. I make a pull request of development into master through the bitbucket ui. It tells me that there's a conflict and I should checkout master locally. Normally when this happens I can fix the conflicts on my machine, and then merge. This time, it shows me master from before the pull request, so there're no conflicts for me to fix.

Comment: I just managed to do it by running 'git merge development'. (I had tried that before redownloading but w.e.) That seems to be your last step so I'm accepting your answer

Comment: I'm sure I clicked accept but the tick isn't green. Weird

Comment: The key is to merge master into dev manually and then push the dev branch to bitbucket and the merge conflicts should be gone

Answer (score 3):

You can merge master into dev locally, then fix conflicts. And after that push dev branch. If you do these, you won't face conflict on BitBocket